# How to hide special symbols in a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

For example we have

```
<p>Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++. </p>
```

In here we want to hide `+++` .
Result must look like

> My Name is Thalapathy. I live in America

Comment: What other special symbols are you expecting and what kind of punctuation do you want to keep?

Comment: only +++, where i want to hide it from users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find in all the elements if this +++ occurs and use regex to replace whatever you want, something like this.
and it will work on all the elements in body, where ever this +++, 3 plus will occur, it will be removed.

```js
$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/\+\+\+/g,"") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++. </p>
```

and if you don't want to use jQuery then go for this. use [Treewalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) for the same.

```js
const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body);
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    const node = treeWalker.currentNode;
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/\+\+\+/g, '');
  }
```

```html
<p>Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++. </p>
```

Comment: I have added one more solution for the same without using jQuery my friend,

Answer (score 1):

If the characters are known and constant (always the same)- then you can do a simple replace - note that you will need to escape the characters. Also note the "g" in the regex / replace - this will allow the replacement globally in the string.

```js
const text="Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++."
const newText = text.replace(/\+\+\+/g,'');
document.querySelector("#result").textContent = newText;
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var str = "Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++."
var x = str.replace(/\+\+\+/ig, '');
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and replace method:

```js
const str1 = 'Hey My Name is Thalapathy. I live in +++America+++.';
const newStr = str1.replace(/\+/g,'')

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: This will replace all instances of "+" - which may occur in the string independantly of the "+++". also - why are the p element tags included within the string?